# SQLite sort only by first WHERE match

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a table that contains 3 columns: `name`, `keywords`, and `weight`, with these data

| name | keywords | weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Kevin | Any, Any, Any, Any | 1 |
| Hugh | Kevin, Any, Any, Any | 1 |

Now I want to select from this table `where` name or keyword match a query and want to sort by name and weight, but the sort should be only for the where that matches the name not the keyword, for example using this query:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE '%Kevin%' OR keyword LIKE '%Kevin%' ORDER BY name, weight DESC;
```

This query will return both `Kevin` and `Hugh` but `Hugu` will be at the first and then `Kevin`, What I need is `Kevin` to be returned first, so if the name matches the query do sort by `name` and `weight` if it's not but the `keyword` is matching the query then do sort by `weight` only.

So the question here, how can I sort depend on if the name match the query or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the matches to name first:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE name LIKE '%Kevin%' OR keyword LIKE '%Kevin%'
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN name LIKE '%Kevin%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END),
         weight DESC;
```

Comment: it's working great but it has 1 issue, it's my bad I didn't mention it in the question If I have two similar names for example `Christoph` and `Chris Evans`, and the user typed `Chris`, `Chris Evans` should be returned first because the first name is exactly matched even if the weight of `Christoph` is higher

Comment: @MohammadHamdan . . . This answers the question you have here.  If you have a different question, then ask as a new question.